# IOS: Merging two NSArrays while updating properties of "duplicates"

Tags: objective-c, merge, comparison, nsarray, nspredicate

**EDIT: Huge edit, sorry for causing confusion!**

I'm currently working on an app wherein I get 2 arrays from a JSON WebService using two different methods.

In the first array, I get the local stock. In the second array I get the supplier stock.

Though I think an image would explain better:

[image: My awesome application diagram]

So the webservices get a number of items in. Array 1 contains some items from local stock and Array 2 contains items from our supplier, with added information like descriptions and such. I'd like to merge both arrays, updating the existing items in our local stock-array1 with the descriptions for the items in supplier stock array 2.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve. All products are identified by an unique identifier-property (not mentioned in the example) and I've overridden isEqual and hash to compensate for that. If a product has a simliar ID, it's considered equal.

```
**Product**

@property id *internalID;
@property id *externalID ;
@property id *localStock;
@property id *supplierStock;
@property id *image;
@property id *productInfo;
```

Now `Webservice 1` returns three products:

**Product 1**

```
*internalID = ABCDEF
*externalID = (null)
*localStock = 15
*supplierStock = (null)
*image = (null)
*productInfo = (null);
```

**Product 2**

```
*internalID = GHIJK
*externalID = (null)
*localStock = 13
*supplierStock = (null)
*image = niceImage.png
*productInfo = @"This Product is Awesome!";
```

**Product 3**

```
*internalID = LMNOP
*externalID = (null)
*localStock = 7
*supplierStock = (null)
*image = (null)
*productInfo = (null);
```

`Webservice 2` returns four products, two of them are also in Array 1:

**Product 1**

```
    *internalID = (null)
    *externalID = 123456
    *localStock = (null)
    *supplierStock = 12
    *image = external_product1image.jpg
    *productInfo = @"This product is also Awesome and in both local stock and supplier stock!";
```

**Product 4**

```
    *internalID = (null)
    *externalID = 23456
    *localStock = (null)
    *supplierStock = 11
    *image = niceImage.png
    *productInfo = @"This Product is Awesome and only available from our supplier!";
```

**Product 3**

```
    *internalID = (null)
    *externalID = 78901
    *localStock = (null)
    *supplierStock = 7
    *image = external)supplierimage.jpg
    *productInfo = @"This product is also Awesome and in both local stock and supplier stock!";
```

Then the `mergedArray` should look like this:

**Product 1**

```
*internalID = ABCDEF
*externalID = 123456
*localStock = 15
*supplierStock = 12
*image = external_product1image.jpg
*productInfo = @"This product is also Awesome and in both local stock and supplier stock!";
```

//So Product 1 from Array 1 merged its properties with Product 1 from Array 2

**Product 2**

```
*internalID = GHIJK
*externalID = (null)
*localStock = 13
*supplierStock = (null)
*image = niceImage.png
*productInfo = @"This Product is Awesome!";
```

**Product 3**

```
*internalID = LMNOP
*externalID = 78901
*localStock = 7
*supplierStock = 7
*image = external)supplierimage.jpg
*productInfo = @"This product is also Awesome and in both local stock and supplier stock!";
```

**Product 4**

```
*internalID = (null)
*externalID = 23456
*localStock = 13
*supplierStock = 11
*image = niceImage.png
*productInfo = @"This Product is Awesome and only available from our supplier!";
```

This is the code I used, but it seems to glitch out at times somehow:

```
- (void) compareArrays:(id)sender metBreedte:(NSString *)breedte metHoogte:(NSString *)hoogte metDiameter:(NSString *)diameter
{
    NSMutableSet *getBandenSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:getBandenArray];      NSUInteger i = 0;

    while (i < [getBandenInfo1Array count]) {
        id getBandenInfo1Object = [getBandenInfo1Array objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([getBandenSet containsObject:getBandenInfo1Object])

        {

            BWBand *getBandenBand = [getBandenSet member:getBandenInfo1Object];

            BWBand *getBandenInfo1Band = getBandenInfo1Object;

            // Do stuff to the Banden (sync)
            getBandenBand.alternatievePrijs = getBandenInfo1Band.alternatievePrijs;
            getBandenBand.itemName = getBandenInfo1Band.itemName;
            getBandenBand.supplierStock = getBandenInfo1Band.supplierStock;
            getBandenBand.grossPrice = getBandenInfo1Band.grossPrice;
            getBandenBand.eancode = getBandenInfo1Band.eancode;
            getBandenBand.EMarked = getBandenInfo1Band.EMarked;
            getBandenBand.garagePrijs = getBandenInfo1Band.garagePrijs;
            getBandenBand.loadIndex = getBandenInfo1Band.loadIndex;
            getBandenBand.brand = getBandenInfo1Band.brand;
            getBandenBand.custPrice = getBandenInfo1Band.custPrice;
            getBandenBand.netPrice = getBandenInfo1Band.netPrice;
            getBandenBand.tyreLabel = getBandenInfo1Band.tyreLabel;
            getBandenBand.TyreLabelFuel = getBandenInfo1Band.TyreLabelFuel;
            getBandenBand.TyreLabelNoise = getBandenInfo1Band.TyreLabelNoise;
            getBandenBand.TyreLabelNoiseLevel = getBandenInfo1Band.TyreLabelNoiseLevel;
            getBandenBand.TyreLabelWet = getBandenInfo1Band.TyreLabelWet;
            getBandenBand.foto = getBandenInfo1Band.foto;
            NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: getBandenBand.colorStock];
            NSString *newString = [string1 substringToIndex:[string1 length]-2];
            NSString *colorStock = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",newString,getBandenInfo1Band.supplierStock];
            getBandenBand.colorStock = colorStock;
           [getBandenSet removeObject:getBandenInfo1Object];
            [getBandenInfo1Array removeObjectIdenticalTo:getBandenInfo1Object];
        } else
        {i++;}

        mergedBandenArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[getBandenArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:getBandenInfo1Array]];
       [mergedBandenArray sortUsingDescriptors:
         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"colorStock" ascending:NO], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"brand" ascending:YES], nil]];}
```

Could all this be done using NSPredicates? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your TableViewController is allocated after your while-loop finished, so that should not be your problem.

Comment: Still checking my code for this. If anyone knows a more elegant solution with NSPredicates to do this comparison, I'm all ears :).

Comment: Do you have the hash and equals ops set up correctly for your object such that two objects will compare equal even if they the different internal data that you want to merge?

Comment: To make the table view refresh properly, simply issue a refresh after your merge is done.  Or don't display the table at all, until you're ready.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to mention that. I'm using AFNetworking to fill both the Arrays asynchronously, then in the completion block of the AFHTTPClient I run the above mentioned code.

I've overridden the hash and isEqualto to make them "equal" if only one unique identifier is the same.

Comment: What does 3+ mean, how to distinguish an object from array1 to array2?

Comment: Sorry, did I forget to put that in? My mind is all over the place haha.

Basically Array 1 has objects with their local properties like localStock, internalID etc. Array 2 contains the supplier objects, with externalID externalStock. I want Array 3 to contain objects with both ExternalID, InternalID and ExternalStock, InternalStock if they appear in both Array 1 and Array 2. Array 2 is the larger one. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've edited my question for more clarity

Comment: @VincentVeldkamp, will there be any unique & non-null key in both arrays to take in consideration?

Comment: Yeah, there's a property named uniqueItemID that makes sure it's the same product.

Comment: The answer from alloc is correct. The only thing I suggest is that you don't code in other language than English. Really bad practice.

Comment: Well, the webservices return those keys for those values, so for sake of ease I've named the properties after those keys. Since it's an in-house application I didn't think it would do much harm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following algorithm does not require that you override `isEqual` and `hash` for your `Product` class:

- First sort both arrays according to the `uniqueItemID` key in ascending order.
- Then traverse both arrays in parallel, and add or merge products from both arrays to the destination array.

If both array are sorted, matching and non-matching products are found easily with a single loop traversing both arrays in parallel.

The following code hopefully demonstrates the idea:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByID = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"uniqueItemID" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted1 = [array1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortByID]];
NSArray *sorted2 = [array2 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortByID]];

NSUInteger i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
NSMutableArray *combined = [NSMutableArray array];
while (i1 < [sorted1 count] && i2 < [sorted2 count]) {
    Product *p1 = sorted1[i1];
    Product *p2 = sorted2[i2];
    switch ([p1.uniqueItemID compare:p2.uniqueItemID]) {
        case NSOrderedAscending:
            // p1 is in first array, but not in second:
            [combined addObject:p1];
            i1++;
            break;
        case NSOrderedDescending:
            // p2 is in second array, but not in first:
            [combined addObject:p2];
            i2++;
            break;
        case NSOrderedSame:
            // p1, p2 have same ID:
            ... update p1 with values from p2 ...
            [combined addObject:p1];
            i1++, i2++;
            break;
    }
}
// Add remaining products from first array:
while (i1 < [sorted1 count]) {
    [combined addObject:sorted1[i1]];
    i1++;
}
// Add remaining products from second array:
while (i2 < [sorted2 count]) {
    [combined addObject:sorted2[i2]];
    i2++;
}
```

Comment: Just tested it in my code, and it's several seconds faster compared to my original code, thanks!

Comment: @VincentVeldkamp: You are welcome! - May I ask how many entries your arrays have, and what the actual timings are (old/new code)? - Only if you can share that information, otherwise ignore this question!

Comment: Well it's about 200+ entries depending on the search. Classes containing a shedload of properties that need to be filtered too. 
I took the most resource-intensive search query and at times my code clocked in at 6 - 7 seconds, yours did a fast 3.57 - 5. (We had some network latency issues during that too). So I'd say that's quite the improvement! 

Regardless of that, your code is easier to read too. Then again, I didn't expect too much from my own code since I only started programming 5 months ago. Somewhere I knew it could be more efficient!

EDIT: Make that 500 entries hehe

Answer (score 3):

1). To merge both arrays:

```
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array2];

NSArray *array = [set allObjects];
```

2). To remove duplicates with the help of NSPredicates:

[1. Filtering Fun with Predicates](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/filtering-fun-with-predicates/)

[2. Hello, NSPredicate](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/14/hello-nspredicate/)

3). To merge & remove duplicates:

```
NSArray *array1, *array2;
MSMutableArray *result = [array1 mutableCopy];
for (id object in array2)
{
  [result removeObject:object];  // remove duplicates if it's already there.
  [result addObject:object];
}
```

Comment: Above is just a logic to have an better idea. Moreover, I'm not aware of response data format. As per mentioned image, there should be an unique key for both arrays to identify the object duplication.